# Return values for dimensions in timeseries query Druid

Tags: time-series, druid

I have Druid timeseries query:

```
{
"queryType": "timeseries",
"dataSource": {
    "type": "union",
    "dataSources": [
        "ds1",
        "ds2"   
    ]
},
"dimensions":["dim1"],
"aggregations": [
    {
        "name": "y1",
        "type": "doubleMax",
        "fieldName": "value1"
    }
],
"granularity": {
    "period": "PT10S",
    "type": "period"
},
"postAggregations": [],
"intervals": "2017-06-09T13:05:46.000Z/2017-06-09T13:06:46.000Z"
```

}

And i want to return the values of the dimensions as well, not just for the aggregations like this:

```
 {
    "timestamp": "2017-06-09T13:05:40.000Z",
    "result": {
        "y1": 28.724306106567383
    }
},
{
    "timestamp": "2017-06-09T13:05:50.000Z",
    "result": {
        "y1": 28.724306106567383
    }
},
```

How do I have to change the query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to use dimension column in time series query that means you are using aggregated data with non aggregated column, this requirement leads to the use of `topN` or `groupBy` query.

`groupBy` query is probably one of the most powerful druid currently supports but it has poor performance as well, instead you can use `topN` query for your purpose.

Link for `topN` documentation and example can be found here:
http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/topnquery.html

Comment: Hello @Jainik,

I want to use timeseries query to get hour wise data but at the same time I want to set dimensions which are not supported by timeseries query.

Can you provide any solution for that.

Thanks

Comment: @Jaymin can you please post a question here with details, examples and/or the things you tried so far to set up a better context?

Comment: time-series query does support dimension, see my above answer, you need to perform some kind of aggregation operation in your query, what is your exact query?

Comment: Can you share your communication id so I can share in details

Answer (score 0):

Is Timeseries() query is not supporting dimension?

I tried it in my project but it is not working.

here is Error:

```
TypeError: queryRep.dataSource(...).dimension is not a function
2|DSP-api  |     at dimensionData (/home/ec2-user/reports/dsp_reports/controllers/ReportController.js:228:22)
```

Let me know if anyone has a solution for this.
TY.